# Java puzzle - trying to make a GUI dispose after a button click

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionevent

**SOLVED: @Desolator has got my coding fully working in the comments below**

ok, so i have made 3 classes which all link through each other:

SplashScreen > ProjectAssignment > CompareSignature

The class i want to talk about is the splashscreen class:

so in this class i have 3 methods:

`public static void createAndShowGUI()`
 - This methos holds all the information for creating and showing the GUI
 - JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome!"); etc...

`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`
 - This Method gives the button i have the ability to be clicked and to open the next GUI
 - if(e.getSource()==enterButton) etc...

`public static void main(String[] args)`
 - This method simply has "createAndShowGUI();" in it so that the GUI shows up when the code is ran

What i need to do is to be able to give the JButton another action to close the SplashScreen class (from the `createAndShowGUI`) when it is clicked but my problem is that:

1. I cannot reference `JFrame frame = new JFrame("");` from the `createAndShowGUI` method in the actionPerformed method as the `createAndShowGUI` method is static
2. Now you're saying "just take the "static" keyword out and place "JFrame frame;" in the variables section"...if i do that then the `public static void main(String[] args)` will not take the `createAndShowGUI();` method and the GUI will not show
3. I have tried putting in the actionPerformed method:

   ```
   if(e.getSource()==enterButton){
   System.exit(0);
   }
   ```

AND...

```
   if(e.getSource()==enterButton){
   frame.dispose();   //Cannot reference frame from static createAndShowGUI method
   }
```

so i am at a loss, is it possible to be able to close the SplashScreen class with a button click? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provde the hole class code? (if it is small enough)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Desolator Sure, i'll edit this post now, it's 72 lines long so its not a big file, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I took the following example from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html). Maybe you took the same because the `createAndShowGUI` method has the same name... I extended it by a button and an appropriate listener which disposes the Frame. Your question was a bit hard to understand for me, but I think this example will answer your question.

```
public class FrameDemo {
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton button = new JButton("Exit");
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
    frame.getContentPane().add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    ActionListener buttonListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.dispose();
        }
    };
    button.addActionListener(buttonListener);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I ave not see this coding beofre but this was nearly the solution, when i saw it i perked up a bit but when I came to reference my button it cannot be referenced from inside the static class, i have my button as JButton enterButton; at the top of the page

Comment: @tombannister in regards to your update: create the JFrame in the constructor of `SplashScreen1`. This will move the `frame` from the static context to the instance.